# MessagePack slower than native node.js JSON

Tags: node.js, msgpack, messagepack

I just installed node-msgpack and tested it against native JSON. MessagePack is much slower. Anyone know why?

Using the authors' own benchmark...

```
node ~/node_modules/msgpack/bench.js 
msgpack pack:   4165 ms
msgpack unpack: 1589 ms
json    pack:   1352 ms
json    unpack: 761 ms
```

Comment: One of the contributors to node-msgpack has addressed this issue here: https://github.com/pgriess/node-msgpack/issues/38#issuecomment-22719635

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'll assume you're talking about https://github.com/pgriess/node-msgpack.

Just looking at the source, I'm not sure how it could be. For example in `src/msgpack.cc` they have the following:

```
Buffer *bp = Buffer::New(sb._sbuf.size);
memcpy(Buffer::Data(bp), sb._sbuf.data, sb._sbuf.size);
```

In node terms, they are allocating and filling a new `SlowBuffer` for every request. You can benchmark the allocation part by doing following:

```
var msgpack = require('msgpack');
var SB = require('buffer').SlowBuffer;
var tmpl = {'abcdef' : 1, 'qqq' : 13, '19' : [1, 2, 3, 4]};

console.time('SlowBuffer');
for (var i = 0; i < 1e6; i++)
    // 20 is the resulting size of their "DATA_TEMPLATE"
    new SB(20);
console.timeEnd('SlowBuffer');

console.time('msgpack.pack');
for (var i = 0; i < 1e6; i++)
    msgpack.pack(tmpl);
console.timeEnd('msgpack.pack');

console.time('stringify');
for (var i = 0; i < 1e6; i++)
    JSON.stringify(tmpl);
console.timeEnd('stringify');

// result - SlowBuffer: 915ms
// result - msgpack.pack: 5144ms
// result - stringify: 1524ms
```

So by just allocating memory for the message they've already spent 60% of `stringify` time. There's just one reason why it's so much slower.

Also take into account that `JSON.stringify` has gotten a lot of love from Google. It's highly optimized and would be difficult to beat.

Comment: **"It's highly optimized and would be difficult to beat."** +1 - No one probably wants to be optimizing C++ string marshaling between msgpack zone and V8 when there's super fast JSON already anyway.

Comment: I agree about JSON.stringify best performances, but what about native JSON implementation like NSJSONSerialization on iOS? Will MessagePack for ObjectiveC better that it?

Comment: @loretoparisi Feel like we might be comparing apples to oranges. Does your program use both Node and ObjectiveC?

Comment: Yep! No ways to compare apples to oranges! Nope, my consideration were about the use of a binary serializer instead of a json serializer on mobile clients (like iOS). See here: https://gist.github.com/frsyuki/2908191

Answer (score 3):

I decided to benchmark all popular Node.js modules for binary encoding Msgpack, along with the PSON (protocol JSON) encoding library, versus JSON, and the results are as follows:

- JSON fastest for encoding unless it includes a binary array
- `msgpack` second fastest normally and fastest when including a binary array
- `msgpack-js` - consistently second to `msgpack`
- `pson` - consistently slower than `msgpack-js`
- `msgpack5` - dog slow always

I have published the benchmarking repository and detailed results at https://github.com/mattheworiordan/nodejs-encoding-benchmarks

Comment: But, were those modules installed natively? It wouldn't be a fair benchmark then, though? (since JSON is native) -- Obviously it will perform faster